# A movie with a guy who is beamed into a ray of light in his garden

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a science-fiction movie trailer I saw for 2 minutes and freaked me out when I was young. Alas, for my own sake most likely and unconsciously, I forgot the name of that movie.

There is this guy who wakes up in his pajamas, goes to the garden and is beamed up through a ray of light into a spaceship or somewhere else. He looks at his people who got different faces and suddenly he takes off his human face to reveal his extra-terrestrial face. I still remember that guy was a bit tough like Jeff Bridges type.

Do you have any idea, which movie it is?

Comment: They live? http://media.paperblog.fr/i/591/5916189/invasion-los-angeles-they-live-john-carpenter-L-pHNa70.jpeg

Comment: Not a pajamas kind of movie.

Comment: Do you remember anything about what the aliens looked like? Also, about when would you have seen it--were you "young" in the 70s, 80s, 90s, or what? Finally, are you sure it was a trailer rather than just part of a movie that was on TV, or a sci-fi TV show?

Comment: Hey everyone, definitely 80's. It is bugging me a bit and I'm asking out of curiosity because the forum exist.It is not a Carpenter's movie , for sure. And Did I say Pajama? OMG I did !!! Sorry, Saturday night in my p(a/y)jama and I kind of ... P(y/a)jama out. ha ha ha

Comment: Again, are you sure it was a trailer? And are you sure he was beamed up in his garden? Do you remember anything about how the aliens looked? The plot element of a guy being beamed up to a spaceship, seeing some aliens and then taking off a human mask to reveal he's an alien reminds me of the 80s Twilight Zone episode "A Day in Beaumont" at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbE4lUcaTX0 , skip to about 17-18 minutes in to watch the unmasking scene.

Comment: Hey @Hynosifi, lack of time but it was. Very 70's and early 80's. Not at Twilight Zone TV show. Cheers.

Comment: Come on my sci-fi friends ! One of you must know !

Answer (score 6):

You might be thinking of "[Strange Invaders](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086374/)", a low-budget sci-fi flick from 1983.

The film centres around a group of aliens living in a mid-west town. There's extensive use of a white lens-flare effect and a major scene in which the aliens remove their human face masks

[image]

You can see the theatrical trailer here

And watch the full movie [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jejxp)