# What 80s movie had aliens putting people in pods, and a boy and father trying to find their mother?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

So I remember an American movie from the 80s where either people are stored in light pods or their 'souls' are. The pods start like drifting towards a ship, I think, and a boy and his father are trying to not get captured yet trying to find the mom's pod.

I was anywhere from 5 to 10 when I saw this movie and I would love to know if my memory serves me right. Does anyone remember an alien movie like this?

Comment: What year did you see the movie? Was it American? Was it a TV movie or feature?

Comment: It was from say 1980 to 1989. I know, too broad, but it was an American movie.

Comment: **You might also want to use a more descriptive question title**

Comment: “I was anywhere from 5 to 10 when I saw this movie” — great, but when were you 10? If you tell us that, we can be sure the move was released before a given year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot description does seem similar to *Strange Invaders* (1983).

Plot spoilers below.

The aliens can make humans shrivel up into empty husks and their souls or essences turn into glowing floating orbs that are stored by the aliens.  A man whose ex wife is one of the aliens seeks to get custody of thier daughter before the aliens leave.

Comment: Also likely asked [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64114/a-movie-with-a-guy-who-is-beamed-into-a-ray-of-light-in-his-garden/67676#67676) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93489/looking-for-a-movie-from-80s-with-glowing-green-orbs-causing-kids-to-shrivel-up/93494#93494).