# Movie about a guy beam-up and losing his human skin

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie dating from the 70's or the 80's where a guy is initially in his garden, with his dog.

He is in his yellow pyjamas.

There is a beam of light that appears in the garden. He enters the beam of light and is beamed-up to somewhere alien. There are several people like him and then all of sudden, he takes off of his human skin to reveal he is an alien.

As you can imagine I was young and the story freaked me out.

Comment: Per [A movie with a guy who is beamed into a ray of light in his garden](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64114/98028), this is most likely *Strange Invaders* (1983). I wouldn't really have anything to add to that answer, hence the comment. If you confirm this is it, we can close as duplicate of [this other, accepted ID question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93489/98028) about the movie. Note that on SFF, dupe-closure on story-ID is mainly to have a "master" ID, an inner working to keep things organised. It doesn't mean your question was bad, quite the contrary in this case :)

Comment: Hi @Jenayah, ty for your comment. Alas, this is not Strange Invaders. I watched the whole movie. The tone of strange invaders is light, almost of hopeful. The movie I'm talking about was scary.

Comment: Alright, the hunt continues then. Though I guess something that looks light now, as an adult, might still have been scary as a child (the skin removal picture). But I haven't seen the movie so I can't really talk :)